# How to identify a string is clickable in android web view?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am loading the html content in android webview. In that I am getting a phone number as the below format.

```
<li>Call 1-500-HM-SAC-20<\/li>
```

So I have to make that phone number string as clickable. How to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your `WebView`:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)); 
                    startActivity(intent); 
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }           
    });
```

Re-update `html` code as:

```
<li>Call <a href="tel:1500HMSAC20">1-500-HM-SAC-20</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    String text = map.get(url);

    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
  }});
```